# Question about series convergence or divergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the following infinite series:

$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k(\sqrt{k}-(-1)^k)}{k-1}$$

I need to determine whether this series converges or diverges. At first I tried the Leibniz convergence theorem. I managed to show that $a_{k} = \frac{(\sqrt{k}-(-1)^k)}{k-1}$ goes to 0, but $a_{k}$ doesn't seem to be decreasing since $a_{2} = \sqrt{2} - 1$ but $a_{3} = \frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2}$. Next I tried to split the series up into 2 series (even and odd numbers) but I am quite sure that you cannot reliably do that without knowing the series converges in the first place. Any suggestions on what to try?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\sqrt{k}/(k-1)$ is monotone decreasing for $k \geqslant 2$ and

$$\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k(\sqrt{k}-(-1)^k)}{k-1}
 = \underbrace{\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k\sqrt{k}}{k-1}}_{\text{convergent alternating series}}
 - \underbrace{\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{k-1}}_{\text{divergent harmonic series}}
$$

The combined series must diverge, since the first sum on the RHS converges to a finite limit and the second sum diverges to $+\infty$ as $n \to \infty$.